# Middle names treated in a random way in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I do not have a problem with all authors who have a first and surname only; e.g `John Smith`. Problems come when introducing middle names. `John P. Smith`, `J. P. Smith`, `J P Smith`, `Smith, J. P.`

All these are treated randomly using `bibtex` **and** `biblatex`. E.g; some authors appear as **Smith (2010)** when using `\citet` from natbib or **(Smith, 2010)** when using `\citep`. However, other authors are shown in the main document as **(J. P. Smith, 2010)** and **J. P. Smith, 2010**.

This made me crazy, and what's more; when creating the MWE for writing the question, the problem disappeared from some authors.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}


\addbibresource{./list.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item Doesn't work: \citet{Sutherland92} stated that \ldots \citep{Sutherland92}.
\item Works \citet{Bliss95} stated that \ldots \citep{Bliss95}.
\item Doesn't work: \citet{Sutherland82} stated that \ldots \citep{Sutherland82}.
\item Works! \citet{AusubelRobinson69} stated that \ldots \citep{AusubelRobinson69}.
\item Works: \citet{Ausubel68} stated that \ldots \citep{Ausubel68} (This doesn't work in the original document!!!)
\item Works: \citet{Bruner61} stated that \ldots \citep{Bruner61} (This doesn't work in the original document!!!)
\item \citet{Bruner66} stated that \ldots \citep{Bruner66} (Also doesn't work in original document :( )

\end{itemize}



\printbibliography 


\end{document}
```

sample `bib` file:

```
@ARTICLE{Bliss95,
  author = {Bliss, Joan},
  title = {Piaget and after: the case of learning science},
  year = {1995},
  editor = {Bliss 95},
  volume = {25},
  number = {1},
  pages = {139-172},
  journal = {Studies in Science Education},
  timestamp = {2012.05.22}
}

@BOOK{Ausubel68,
  author = {Ausubel, David P.},
  title = {Education Psychology: A cognitive View},
  year = {1968},
  publisher = {Holt, Rinhart and Winston},
  address = {New York},
  timestamp = {2012.05.22}
}


@BOOK{AusubelRobinson69,
  author = {Ausubel, David P. and Robinson, Floyd G.},
  title = {School Learning: an Introduction to Educational Psychology},
  year = {1969},
  publisher = {Holt, Reinhart and Winston},
  address = {New York},
  timestamp = {2012.05.22}
}


@BOOK{Sutherland92,
  author = {Sutherland, Peter},
  title = {Cognitive Development Today: Piaget and his Critics},
  year = {1992},
  publisher = {Sage Publications Ltd},
  address = {London, UK},
  timestamp = {2012.05.22}
}

@ARTICLE{Sutherland82,
  author = {Sutherland, Paul A.},
  title = {An Expansion of Peel's Describer - Explainer Stage Theory},
  year = {1982},
  volume = {34},
  number = {1},
  pages = {69-76},
  journal = {Educational Review},
  timestamp = {2012.05.22}
}

@ARTICLE{Bruner61,
  author = {Bruner, Jerome S.},
  title = {The Act of Discovery},
  year = {1961},
  editor = {Bruner 61},
  volume = {31},
  number = {1},
  pages = {31-32},
  journal = {Harvard Educational Review},
  publisher = {Bruner 61},
  timestamp = {2012.05.22}
}

@BOOK{Bruner66,
  author = {Jerome S. Bruner},
  title = {Toward a Theory of Instruction},
  year = {1966},
  publisher = {Bruner 66},
  address = {Cambridge Mass},
  timestamp = {2012.05.22}
}
```

[image]

I am more confused now as I keep adding references (that do not work originally) to the sample file and they work properly. It's only the Sutherlands that don't work in this sample. Does anyone know what is happening?

**Edit**:
Before I read the comments, I noticed that in the `bbl` file, the entries where the problem occur have the following data in the entry:

```
 \entry{Sutherland92}{book}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=1,hash=19d7df1fb93fb36727a88eb47c7919c6}{Sutherland}{S\bibinitperiod}{Peter}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=1,hash=19d7df1fb93fb36727a88eb47c7919c6}{Sutherland}{S\bibinitperiod}{Peter}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \list{location}{1}{%
        {London, UK}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Sage Publications Ltd}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{19d7df1fb93fb36727a88eb47c7919c6}
      \strng{fullhash}{19d7df1fb93fb36727a88eb47c7919c6}
      \field{sortinit}{S}
      \field{labelyear}{1992}
      \field{labeltitle}{Cognitive Development Today: Piaget and his Critics}
      \field{title}{Cognitive Development Today: Piaget and his Critics}
      \field{year}{1992}
    \endentry
```

`uniquename=1` is repeated twice in each entry. However, for the working entries, the first `uniquename` is equal to zero.

**Edit2**: uniquename=false as an option solves it, I get it now :)

Comment: Have you tried with `uniquename=false` as an option of `biblatex`?

Comment: I did find this in the log but It's not stopping the file from compiling. However, I just found something that may help. See edit.

Comment: @Guido, thanks a lot, that did it. If you submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `.bib` file there are two different authors with the same family name, thus `biblatex` (`biber`) disambiguates then by introducing the initials in the references and citations. Using the `biber` backend (`backend=biber`) one can prevent (and customise) the behaviour using the

```
uniquename=false
```

option of `biblatex`.