# disambiguation surprise in textcite with biblatex, biber, and authoryear

Tags: biblatex, biber

Here is behavior that surprised me and took me a while to track down, so I thought I would share it.  In

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}
\begin{document}
\textcite{fama-french:1992},
\textcite{fama-french:1997},
\textcite{fama-french:2002},
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with the test.bib file of

```
@article{ fama-french:1997,
  year =         1997 ,
  author =       { Eugene F. Fama And Kenneth R. French },
  title =        { Industry costs of equity },
  journal =      { Journal of Financial Economics },
  volume =       43,
  pages =        { 153 - 193 }
}

@article{ fama-french:2002,
  year =         2002,
  author =       { Eugene F. Fama and Kenneth R. French },
  title =        { The Equity Premium },
  volume =       57,
  journal =      { The Journal of Finance },
  pages = { 637-659 }
}

@article{ fama-french:1992,
  year =         1992,
  author =       { Eugene F. Fama and Kenneth French },
  title =        { The Cross-Section of Expected Stock Returns },
  volume =       47,
  journal =      { The Journal of Finance },
  pages =        { 427-465 }
}
```

then the latex file will cite as `Fama and K. French (1992)` (and `Fama and K.R. French (1997)`) instead of `Fama and French (1992)`.  Apparently, if initials are not completely identical, then the year alone is not sufficient disambiguation.  it's probably a feature rather than a bug, but not immediately obvious behavior.

Comment: Not sure if there's a question here. You can turn this behaviour off with `uniquename=false` (so all will show up as "Fama and French".)

Comment: As far as `biblatex` is concerned, `Kenneth R. French` and `Kenneth French` are two different people, and the `uniquename` option (by default set to `uniquename=full` in `authoryear` style) disambiguates the two using initials. See also the pretty-much-duplicate [Middle names treated in a random way in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73289/), [Initials in the bibliography. uniquename not working correctly in biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162212/) as well as [biblatex authoryear-comp and name aliases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37857/) for a bit of background.